# How to Set/Get value from a Dependency Property of a usercontrol?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I have an UserControl that has a grid in it and  show a list of person and i wane when clicked on row in my grid get selected row item in my view model.my problem is that i cant get selected row in my usercontrol in my view3model SelectedPersonModel .Here's the code that I'm using:
my UserControl Xaml Code and Code Behind:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Control:UcPersonList}}}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Control:UcPersonList}}}"/>
</Grid>
```

```
 public partial class UcPersonList : UserControl
    {
        public UcPersonList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

    #region PersonListProperty


    public static readonly DependencyProperty PersonListProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("PersonList", typeof(BindingList<PersonModel>), typeof(UcPersonList),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
        {
            DefaultValue = new BindingList<PersonModel>(),
            BindsTwoWayByDefault = true
        });

    public BindingList<PersonModel> PersonList
    {
        get { return (BindingList<PersonModel>)GetValue(PersonListProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(PersonListProperty, value);

        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region SelectedPerson



    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedRowProperty =
   DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedRow", typeof(PersonModel), typeof(UcPersonList),
       new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
       {
           DefaultValue = new PersonModel(),
           BindsTwoWayByDefault = true

       });

    public PersonModel SelectedRow
    {
        get { return (PersonModel)GetValue(SelectedRowProperty ); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(SelectedRowProperty , value);

        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

in my view  I have :

```
<my:UcPersonList x:Name="uclist" Grid.Row="2" PersonList="{Binding Path=PersonList,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedRow="{Binding Path=SelectedPersonModel ,Mode=TwoWay}"  />
```

And my ViewModel:

```
    public MainViewModel()
   {

       SelectedPersonModel = new PersonModel();
       PersonList = new BindingList<PersonModel>();
       PersonList.Add(new PersonModel { FirstName = "A", LastName = "AA", Age = 19 });
       PersonList.Add(new PersonModel { FirstName = "B", LastName = "BB", Age = 25 });
       PersonList.Add(new PersonModel { FirstName = "C", LastName = "CC", Age = 30 });
   }
  public BindingList<PersonModel> PersonList { get; set; }
  public PersonModel SelectedPersonModel{get;set;}
```

I want that set  User Control PersonList from my viewmodel and get selectedRow
Property value in viewmodel  SelectedPersonModel property.how do it?

Answer (score 1):

Simply bind your `SelectedRow` property to `SelectedPersonViewModel`

Also, the selection won't appear with the code you posted because the `SelectedPersonModel` set in your ViewModel does not exist in your `PersonList`. See comments in code below.

```
   public MainViewModel()
   {
       SelectedPersonModel = new PersonModel();
       PersonList = new BindingList<PersonModel>();
       PersonList.Add(new PersonModel { FirstName = "A", LastName = "AA", Age = 19 });
       PersonList.Add(new PersonModel { FirstName = "B", LastName = "BB", Age = 25 });
       PersonList.Add(new PersonModel { FirstName = "C", LastName = "CC", Age = 30 });

      // Either add SelectedPerson to list
      PersonList.Add(SelectedPersonModel);

      // or set SelectedPersonModel to an item that already exists in the list
      SelectedPersonModel = PersonList.FirstOrDefault();
   }
```

Also I agree with HB, don't set your DataContext inside your UserControl. It should be set when the UserControl is used, not as part of the UserControl.

Comment: I Correct my UserControl Code ,i binde SelectedRow to SelectedPersonModel :SelectedRow="{Binding Path=SelectedPersonModel ,Mode=TwoWay}" ,but when I Select a row from Datagrid my SelectedPersonModel is Null

Comment: @mtaboy Try switching your `BindingList` to an `ObservableCollection`. Not sure if that'll make a difference, but that's the only thing I see in your code that looks unusual. I believe `BindingList` behaves differently than `ObservableCollection`

Comment: i use from ObservableCollection  but my prolble not resolved.in fact ,i want  an usercontrol that show a list from an items such as person  and can  get selcected item from it.does my implementation wrong for this?

Answer (score 0):

Do not set the DataContext on the UC, it affects your "outer" binding.

Comment: Where I must set DataContext?

Comment: I said "do not" not "set it elsewhere".

Comment: @HB While I agree with you, your answer does not answer the question